# react-navigation always mount initial screen when StackNavigator renders (v5)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

In react-navigation v5, is there a way to always mount/render an initial screen to be the first screen in the stack when the StackNavigator renders?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `initialRouteName` prop inside **Stack.Navigator** of your application.

Example Code :

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="HomeScreen" // Add this to set initial screen
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="UploadScreen" component={UploadScreen}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

[Refer more information](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)

Comment: Is there anyway that we can pass the initial route name dynamically depends on my condition like if user registered i want to login screen to my initial route.

Answer (score 0):

Use `initialRouteName` props (The name of the route to render on first load of the navigator) if you want a specific screen, otherwise the first stack screen will be rendered by default.

Doc - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/